# In UK visit visa, what should I answer in Do you have a valid national identity card?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I'm a perminant resident of UAE. My nationality is Jordanian. Im confused as to how I should answer this question because my Jordan ID card is expired however I do have a valid UAE ID card "resident ID card". So does this question mean my home country ID card?

Answer (score 7):

Yes it does.

A national ID card is issued to citizens. A residence card demonstrates your authority to reside as a PR in UAE, it is not a national ID card.

So the answer to that question is "No, I don't have a valid national identity card".